# What is the Cauchy principal value of the integral PV$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{(a-1)}}{x-1}dx$?

Tags: calculus

When I am learning for the Cauchy type integral equation in a video, I encounter such a integral. There is another integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{(a-1)}}{x+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{sin a\pi}$. The integral be done by a variable transformation $x\to \frac{t}{1-t}$, after which the integral become $\int_0^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{1-a-1}$. Then appealing to the special value of the Beta function $\beta (a,1-a)=\frac{\pi}{sin a\pi}, 0<a<1$, one gets the result.

The video says that similarly, one can get the result of the integral $P.V.\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{(a-1)}}{x-1}dx=-\pi cot a\pi$. However, when I try this transformation to solve the problem in the title, the integral cannot transform to a Beta function form. Moreover, the integral itself is a improper integral and only the Cauchy principal value is available.

My problem is that how to do this integral? Maybe I should use another variable transformation?

Comment: What have you tried? You'll have to show what you've done to get the answer here.

Comment: Take a tour: [math.stackexchange.com/tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: [math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: Thanks. I will modify my question.@Zaragosa

Comment: Did you managed to get a proper variable transformation? I think I'm watching the same videos you were.